Is there any way I can get all the 'Developer Console' or 'DevTools Console' data from the browser to my VS Code IDE?
I was working on a Next.js 14 app route project with AI, where it functions similarly to Copilot. I provide both browser and server errors, and it debugs and gives the correct solution. However, the problem is that I'm not finding the right way to get error log data from the browser to the IDE.
I tried using console-browserify, but it didn't work as expected. I also tried searching on ChatGPT, but it wasn't able to fulfill my needs. I'm expecting all the console log data to be displayed in the terminal of my VS Code.

you should try Console Ninja extension i been using it. it will display your console.log no matter client or server component
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WallabyJs.console-ninja
